# How to make Roboguice 3.0 jar from sources

Tags: android, maven, roboguice

I need to migrate from roboguice 2.0 to 3.0 in order to use the fragments from API 14 instead of the ones from support v4 library. I've seen that on github there is a release for 3.0 https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/releases/tag/roboguice-3.0, but with the sources, not the jar. On http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/roboguice/roboguice/ I see that the last jar is 3.0-alpha-2, from May 2014. 
My question is how to make a jar from the sources from github?

Comment: Here are their official instructions for maintainers: https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/MaintainerInstructions

Comment: Which build system do you use for your app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the jars of RoboGuice 3 here : 
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.roboguice%7Croboguice%7C3.0%7Cjar

If you need to compile RoboGuice from sources, and it's rarely the case, except for instance if you fork RoboGuice, then you basically have to :

- clone RG repo from GitHub
- `mvn clean install -P 'guice'`

But I guess that all you want is the jars from RoboGuice, nothing else.